# C# Math.Exp differences between Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I have a NET project that is successfully being developed on two platforms: Windows and Ubuntu (Mono). It's very math oriented and even though everything works as expected we did find some discrepancies in results affecting 13th or 14th decimal. As we have some automated tests to verify algorithm correctness, these tend to fail due to number differences.

After a lot of research we nailed the problem down to `Math.Exp` giving different results on two platforms for identical inputs. The results are not 100% inconsistent but still even the slightest difference for certain inputs yields the final output difference that is detected by our tests.

First of all, what would be the reason for this slightly different behavior? Isn't `Math.Exp` executed directly on the CPU? BTW, both platforms are Intel based.

If this cannot be rectified (I don't see how it can be), is there an alternative `Exp` implementation (as fast as `Math.Exp`) that we could use on both platforms?

I know we could use `Math.Pow(Math.E, x)` but quick search reveals that this is 2x slower than `Math.Exp`. Furthermore, it could suffer from the same problem.

Comment: (Quoting) "I know we could use Math.Pow(Math.E, x) but quick search reveals that this is 2x slower than Math.Exp. Furthermore, it could suffer from the same problem." Be pragmatic about it. Since you can't (easily) make the Windows and Ubuntu versions of Math.Exp compute identically, then still try to refactor into using Math.Pow, measure, and decide for yourself if the performance are good enough. 'HTH,